# Debugging nans in the backward pass

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to debug a somewhat complicated and non-canonical NN architecture. Computing the forward pass is fine and is giving me the expected results, but when I try to optimize using Adam or any of the standard optimizers, even after one iteration with a very small learning rate I get nans everywhere. I'm trying to localize them and was wondering if there's a way to catch the first occurrence of a nan and detect in which op it arose? I tried `tf.add_check_numerics_ops()` but it doesn't appear to be doing anything, or perhaps I'm using it incorrectly.

Comment: Where you able to solve that? I'm having the same issue

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Debugging NaNs can be tricky, especially if you have a large network. [`tf.add_check_numerics_ops()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/add_check_numerics_ops) adds ops to the graph that assert that each floating point tensor in the graph does not contain any NaN values, but does not run these checks by default. Instead it returns an op that you can run periodically, or on every step, as follows:

```py
train_op = ...
check_op = tf.add_check_numerics_ops()

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run([train_op, check_op])  # Runs training and checks for NaNs
```

Comment: The problem is that once I run the train_op, the nans are propagated throughout the network and so it's useless to find the cause then. What I'd like to do is run the forward and backward passes, and as soon as a nan is generated an exception is thrown by the offending op.

Comment: If you run the `train_op` and `check_op` together, you should get an error that reports the first node that has a NaN - you can catch the `tf.InvalidArgumentError` that is raised, and extract the op from its `.op` property. With a handle to the op, you can access its `op.inputs[0]` property to see which tensor had NaN values.

Comment: @MohammedAlQuraishi  If this is the accepted answer then you should [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it. :)

Comment: Do you need `tf.control_dependencies` since the order is undefined otherwise? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43844510/is-session-runfetches-guaranteed-to-execute-its-fetches-arguments-in-order

Comment: what's the recommended solution when your graph has conditionals or while_loops?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could add Print ops to suspect ops print values, something like this

```py
print_ops = []
for op in ops:
  print_ops.append(tf.Print(op, [op],
                   message='%s :' % op.name, summarize=10))
print_op = tf.group(*print_ops)
sess.run([train_op, print_op])
```

To add to all ops, you could do a loop along the lines of [`add_check_numerics_ops`](https://tensorflow.googlesource.com/tensorflow/+/master/tensorflow/python/ops/numerics.py#63).