# Tracking NaNs in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, nan

I have a fairly complex network through which I am attempting to track NaNs that only occur after several hundred thousand iterations.  Based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34046048/debugging-nans-in-the-backward-pass) I added a check_op using `tf.add_check_numerics_ops` and caught `tf.errors.InvalidArgumentError`, but the op it appears to be crashing on is a variable read (specifically a read of beta for the batch_norm layer).

I am at a bit of a loss for how to proceed from here.  I am thinking some other op beforehand caused the variable to be set to NaN, but then why was it not caught by the check_numerics at that point instead?  The read being the first place the NaN is caused does not seem likely, but that is what the system seems to be telling me!

If anyone has any advice on how I might track this bug further down, it would be much appreciated!

Some more information that might be relevant:

1) If I break in my except block and run just the read op (doing something like `sess.run([err.op.inputs[0]])`) it consistently gives me NaN.

2) If I re-run the entire network, my check_op consistently trips on this same read, but at different steps.

3) [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X504B.png) is the network loss on one of these runs.  It spikes up on a single iteration.

4) Here is a dump of the read op's NodeDef

```
name: "base_networks/bn/beta/read"
op: "Identity"
input: "base_networks/bn/beta"
device: "/device:GPU:0"
attr {
  key: "T"
  value {
    type: DT_FLOAT
  }
}
attr {
  key: "_class" 
  value {
    list {
      s: "loc:@base_networks/bn/beta"
    }
  }
}
```

As well as its input's NodeDef:

```
name: "base_networks/bn/beta"
op: "Variable"
device: "/device:GPU:0"
attr {
  key: "container"
  value {
    s: ""
  }
}
attr {
  key: "dtype"
  value {
    type: DT_FLOAT
  }
}
attr {
  key: "shape"
  value {
    shape {
      dim {
        size: 4
      }
    }
  }
}
attr {
  key: "shared_name"
  value {
    s: ""
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you plot/printed the loss of your model? NaNs after a couple iteration may happen when the model is diverging.

Comment: Thanks for the reply -- When tracking the loss, it looks fine up until the iteration the NaNs get introduced, and then shoots up to what is essentially random performance.  So I don't think it is an issue with the model diverging.

Comment: I added an image of the loss to the end of my post.

Comment: What is the read op? Could you paste its definition as well?

Comment: I added a dump of the op's NodeDef proto above.

Comment: This beta is defined within the batch_norm function in contrib.layers [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v0.11.0rc2/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/layers.py).  I am using tensorflow v0.11.0rc2 .