# Tensorflow 'nan' Loss and '-inf' weights, Even with 0 Learning Rate

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I am training Deep Convolutional Neural Network on AWS GPU Machine.
Dataset -> Google SVHN
Training Size -> 200,000+

I get Loss = 'nan' and W = '-inf'

#### Even with 0 Learning Rate

```
Loss at step 0: 14.024256
Minibatch accuracy: 5.8%
Learning rate :  0.0
W :  [ 0.1968164   0.19992708  0.19999388  0.19999997]
b :  [ 0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1]        

Loss at step 52: 14.553226
Minibatch accuracy: 5.9%
Learning rate :  0.0
W :  [ 0.19496706  0.19928116  0.19977403  0.1999999 ]
b :  [ 0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1]

# STEP 53 ---> LOSS : NAN, ALL WEIGHTS STILL OKAY
Loss at step 53: nan
Minibatch accuracy: 6.4%
Learning rate :  0.0
W :  [ 0.19496706  0.19928116  0.19977403  0.1999999 ]
b :  [ 0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1]

# STEP 54 ---> LOSS : NAN, WEIGHTS START GOINT TO -INF
Loss at step 54: nan
Minibatch accuracy: 49.2%
Learning rate :  0.0
W :  [       -inf        -inf  0.19694112        -inf]
b :  [-inf -inf  0.1 -inf]

# STEP 54 ---> LOSS : NAN, W & B  -INF
Loss at step 55: nan
Minibatch accuracy: 46.9%
Learning rate :  0.0
W :  [-inf -inf -inf -inf]
b :  [-inf -inf -inf -inf]
```

I have tried following techniques:

1. Used Several Different Optimisers (Adam, SGD, etc)
2. Used different Activation functions on last layer (ReLU, Sigmoid, tanH)
3. Initialized Weights and biases in different ways
4. Tried Different Learning rates and rate-decays (from 0.001 to 0.0001)
5. I thought there might be an error in my dataset, so removed first 10000 entries. Didn't work

None of these things seemed to work for me.
I am still getting 'nan' loss after 1500 steps.

My Code :

#### Weight Initalization

```
W1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([6, 6, 1, K], stddev=0.1))    
B1 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, tf.float32, [K]))
# Similarly W2, B2, W3, B3, W4 and B4

W5_1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([N, 11], stddev=0.1))
B5_1 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, tf.float32, [11]))
# Similarly W5_2, B5_2, W5_3, B5_3, W5_4, B5_4, W5_5, B5_5, 

# Model
Y1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.conv2d(X, W1, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME') + B1)
# Similarly Y2 and Y3 with stride 2

shape = Y3.get_shape().as_list()
YY = tf.reshape(Y3, shape=[-1, shape[1] * shape[2] * shape[3]])
Y4 = tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(YY, W4) + B4)
YY4 = tf.nn.dropout(Y4, pkeep)

Ylogits_1 = tf.matmul(YY4, W5_1) + B5_1
# Ylogits_2,3,4,5 

Y_1 = tf.nn.softmax(Ylogits_1)
# Y_2,3,4,5
```

#### Loss

```
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(Ylogits_1, Y_[:,1])) +\
# ....... (Ylogits_5, Y_[:,5]))

train_prediction = tf.pack([Y_1, Y_2, Y_3, Y_4, Y_5])    
train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(alpha).minimize(cross_entropy)

W_s = tf.pack([tf.reduce_max(tf.abs(W1)),tf.reduce_max(tf.abs(W2)),tf.reduce_max(tf.abs(W3)),tf.reduce_max(tf.abs(W4))])
b_s = tf.pack([tf.reduce_max(tf.abs(B1)),tf.reduce_max(tf.abs(B2)),tf.reduce_max(tf.abs(B3)),tf.reduce_max(tf.abs(B4))])

model_saver = tf.train.Saver()
```

#### Tensorflow Session

```
for step in range(num_steps):
    # I have set the Learning Rate = 0
    learning_rate = 0
    batch_data = train_data[step*batch_size:(step + 1)*batch_size, :, :, :]
    batch_labels = label_data[step*batch_size:(step + 1)*batch_size, :]

    feed_dict = {X : batch_data, Y_ : batch_labels, pkeep : 0.80, alpha : learning_rate}
    _, l, train_pred, W, b = session.run([train_step, cross_entropy, train_prediction, W_s, b_s], feed_dict=feed_dict)

    if (step % 20 == 0): 
        print('Loss at step %d: %f' % (step, l))
        print('Minibatch accuracy: %.1f%%' % acc(train_pred, batch_labels[:,1:6]))
        print('Learning rate : ', learning_rate)
        print('W : ', W)
        print('b : ', b)
        print('    ')
```

#### Since No learning takes place if Learning Rate is 0, How can loss and weights change and ho to nan and -inf.

Any Help is appreciated.

Comment: This is more general advice, but the first step is to figure out where numeric issues are being introduced. Could you try running the output of [add_check_numerics_ops](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/control_flow_ops/debugging_operations#add_check_numerics_ops) along [with your training op](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34046048/debugging-nans-in-the-backward-pass/34049684#34049684)?

Answer (score 2):

I have seen this happening when one label is out of range. Can you check that your labels are all in the range of (0 - (num_labels-1) ) ?

Comment: "label out of range". That helped me get back on track. I'm working on a problem that outputs values in the range [100-300]. What I'm doing now is to divide the labels by 100. Training seems fine now. At inference time, I just need to remember to multiply those predictions by 100.

Answer (score 2):

While I cannot say for certain what problem your code has, there are two general ways to debug NaN's and Inf's that I can recommmend.

The first is simply going over your code and look for any operation that might not be defined over its input. The operations that come to my mind immediately (since they are very common) are division (by 0) and logs (of negative values). This includes part of your code where this is not obvious, since you apply a more complex function that entails these operations. In your code, this include s`tf.reduce_mean` (which includes a problematic division if your input set sums to 0 - which might happen if it has length 0, too).

The second is one of tensorflow's most useful op's: [tf.add_check_numerics_ops](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/add_check_numerics_ops) that creates an op (i.e. an operation that you need to call with session.run) that will tell you which computation node is either `inf` of `nan` ...

Comment: An example for how to use add_check_numeric_ops can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34046048/debugging-nans-in-the-backward-pass

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar issue with a CNN implementation. And after implementing all the checks from other answers (assert input and label values are in range, no division by zero, etc.) the problem still persisted: after one training step the CNN would produce nan-s at output (logits).

Interestingly I have stumbled upon a "workaround": if I replace `tf.train.AdamOptimizer` with `tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer` the nan values do not appear any more. This is very confusing.

Hope this helps someone. I will update the answer when I find out more.