# 'Model diverged with loss = NaN' , when number of classes increases even with small learning rate . [tensorflow]

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning, softmax

I have a network based on alexnet  for age classification. 
when I train network for 8 classes it works totally fine but when I increase classes to 60 or 100 I get "'Model diverged with loss = NaN" 
I already decrease learning rate to 0.00000001 or even 0.0  and decrease bath size to 1 even . but did'nt  help .

my loss function is :

```
def loss(logits, labels):
    labels = tf.cast(labels, tf.int32)   #trying to avoig log(0)
    shape = [logits.get_shape()[0], 57]
    epsilon = tf.constant(value=0.1, shape=shape)
    logits = logits + epsilon    



    cross_entropy = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
       logits= logits,labels= labels, name='cross_entropy_per_example')
    cross_entropy_mean = tf.reduce_mean(cross_entropy, name='cross_entropy',)
    tf.add_to_collection('losses', cross_entropy_mean)
    losses = tf.get_collection('losses')
    regularization_losses = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.REGULARIZATION_LOSSES)
    total_loss = cross_entropy_mean + LAMBDA * sum(regularization_losses)
    tf.summary.scalar('tl (raw)', total_loss)
    #total_loss = tf.add_n(losses + regularization_losses, name='total_loss')
    loss_averages = tf.train.ExponentialMovingAverage(0.9, name='avg')
    loss_averages_op = loss_averages.apply(losses + [total_loss])
    for l in losses + [total_loss]:
        tf.summary.scalar(l.op.name + ' (raw)', l)
        tf.summary.scalar(l.op.name, loss_averages.average(l))
    with tf.control_dependencies([loss_averages_op]):
        total_loss = tf.identity(total_loss)
    return total_loss
```

any idea how to solve the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One other possible thing to try is to change the initialization of your weights, sometimes reducing the magnitude can help. You can also look at using `add_check_numeric_ops` to debug exactly where the NaNs are coming from, as shown in this example:
[Debugging nans in the backward pass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34046048/debugging-nans-in-the-backward-pass)

Comment: xavier@Pete Warden  I am using xavier initialization do you think it should be changed?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are dealing with an imbalanced dataset and you are adding a small value when you have no classes in the batch, right? 
I don't see any weights in the code you posted, as far as I know adding a small constant to the logits would make sense using weights for classes. Anyway assuming the rest is correct, maybe a value 0.1 is relatively too big and may cause instability. Try with a very very small one, like 1e-8. Also you can just add a single constant that is added element wise to the whole logits tensor like this:

```
epsilon = tf.constant(1e-8)
logits = logits + epsilon
```