# Keras + Tensorflow : Debug NaNs

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, keras

Here is a great question on how to find the first occurence of Nan in a tensorflow graph:

[Debugging nans in the backward pass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34046048/debugging-nans-in-the-backward-pass)

The answer is quite helpful, here is the code from it:

```
train_op = ...
check_op = tf.add_check_numerics_ops()

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run([train_op, check_op])  # Runs training and checks for NaNs
```

Apparently, running the training and the numerical check at the same time will result in an error report as soon as Nan is encountered for the first time.

How do I integrate this into Keras ?
In the documentation, I can't find anything that looks like this.

I checked the code, too.
The update step is executed here:
https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/engine/training.py

There is a function called `_make_train_function` where an operation to compute the loss and apply updates is created. This is later called to train the network.

I could change the code like this (always assuming that we're running on a tf backend):

```
check_op = tf.add_check_numerics_ops()

self.train_function = K.function(inputs, 
    [self.total_loss] + self.metrics_tensors + [check_op],
    updates=updates, name='train_function', **self._function_kwargs)
```

I'm currently trying to set this up properly and not sure whether the code above actually works.
Maybe there is an easier way ?

Comment: Did you find an answer if this works or not? I've the same problem as you had last year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been running into the exact same problem, and found an alternative to the `check_add_numerics_ops()` function. Instead of going that route, I use the TensorFlow Debugger to walk through my model, following the example in https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/debugger to figure out exactly where my code produces `nan`s. This snippet should work for replacing the TensorFlow Session that Keras is using with a debugging session, allowing you to use `tfdbg`.

```python
from tensorflow.python import debug as tf_debug
sess = K.get_session()
sess = tf_debug.LocalCLIDebugWrapperSession(sess)
K.set_session(sess)
```